# Trouble Saving a Hugging Face Dimensionality Reduced Model and Converting in ONNX for Use in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, huggingface

I am trying to create word embeddings using Hugging face **all-MiniLM-L6-v2** pre-trained model. The vector length is 384 but I need to reduce the dimensionality for time improvement in similarity search from 384 to 128.

The implementation in python was straight-forward but when I tried in NodeJS (Since my codebase is in NodeJs) I got stuck. Used Xenova Transformers (A hugging Face NodeJS implementation) but I am unable to load the custom 128dim model.

Note: Since the implementation of dimensionality reduction in python is easy pesy and I have already done and tested it there hence I just want to use the model saved in python implementation and use it in NodeJS.

Here is what I did:

1.Generated word embeddings using sentence transformer (all-MiniLM-L6-v2):

```
#Model for which we apply dimensionality reduction
model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
#New size for the embeddings
new_dimension = 128
######## Reduce the embedding dimensions ########
pca_train_sentences = ls
train_embeddings = model.encode(pca_train_sentences, convert_to_numpy=True)
#Compute PCA on the train embeddings matrix
pca = PCA(n_components=new_dimension)
pca.fit(train_embeddings)
pca_comp = np.asarray(pca.components_)

# We add a dense layer to the model, so that it will produce directly embeddings with the new size
dense = models.Dense(in_features=model.get_sentence_embedding_dimension(), out_features=new_dimension, bias=False, activation_function=torch.nn.Identity())
dense.linear.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(pca_comp))
model.add_module('dense', dense)
model.save('models/my-128dim-model-local')
```

2. Performed Dimensionality Reduced to get vector length of 128 instead of 384, followed [Dimensionality Reduction](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/training/distillation/dimensionality_reduction.py)
3. I had to use this model from within Node JS, found the implementation [Xenova Transformers](https://github.com/xenova/transformers.js)

```
import { env } from '@xenova/transformers';
env.localModelPath = 'local/';
env.allowRemoteModels = false;
import { pipeline } from '@xenova/transformers';
const extractor = await pipeline('feature-extraction', 'my-128dim-model');
const sentences = ['This is an example sentence', 'Each sentence is converted'];
const output = await extractor(sentences, { pooling: 'mean', normalize: true });
console.log(output);
```

4. I need to convert my dimensionality reduced model to onnx as briefed so I can it in above, so I followed the in instruction here: Convert To Onnx. Ran the following script:

```
python -m scripts.convert --quantize --model_id ../my-128dim-model --task feature-extraction
```

This works but I am not getting a 128 dim vector but 384 still. What am I doing wrong? Although when I try to convert a pretrained model from hugging face lib it works perfectly.